# Good resources for looking under the hood of webforms?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

At my workplace we use ASP.NET with Webforms (for legacy code) and MVC.

I have been learning about ASP.NET and how it works "under the hood" and as I understand it Webforms (and I am guessing MVC) hook in as HttpHandlers and carry application implementation under ProcessRequest(...).

MVC is easy enough since the source is open, however I have had more trouble with Webforms.

Basically I want to learn where Webforms, Masterpages, Views,  How these things like "control trees" work, etc. fit in and how they work on a low level starting at the ProcessRequest call. Where are some good free resources on learning about this? I attempted to download the ASP.NET Webforms source code from Codeplex, but I was not able to locate a source download (not opensource I'm guessing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download .NET source for reference here:

<strike>http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx</strike> ([archive.org's copy from Feb 8, 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20140208045133/http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx))

**edit**
now available via github

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet

Comment: the .net framework was open sourced and is available via github: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet

Answer (score 1):

.NET source is also available for viewing; see this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx

Also, Visual Studio has been "equipped" with ability to step through .NET's code. Enable this in VS Tools Debugging > General > Enable .NET Framework source stepping, then follow the instructions (there will be a kind of a one-time setup wizard).